# Error while passing current date from c# to oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0

I am trying to pass current date to oracle parameters as shown below but I am getting error please anyone can help ?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Error_Time", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```

error below

> ```
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259
> ```

and this way

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Error_Time", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

but getting error below

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string

Comment: why dont you just pass the parameter as DateTime?

Comment: because I am getting error `PL/SQL: Statement ignored
  Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET
  ErrorCode=-2147467259`

Comment: One side note: unless you *really* want the system local time of wherever the code is running, it would be better to use `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: @JonSkeet what is the defferance between `DateTime.now` and `DateTime.UtcNow` ?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation before asking?

Comment: @JonSkeet honestly yea I take fast look not very deep

Comment: So before asking someone else to put in time to help you, please put time in yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using `DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()` will pass in a string which is not what you want. When parameterizing your Sql statements always pass the types in their native format and never as strings. In this example you should pass in the `DateTime` instance as follows (*see below*).

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Error_Time", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

---

Also check the parameter name, I believe that parameter names in oracle should be prefixed with `:` but this might just be in the query and not the parameter name itself.

Comment: @actully I need the full time date & time ... and your are right parameter names in oracle should be prefixed with : but I am using function so no need for that

Comment: @sam - then use `DateTime.Now` (omit the `.Date` call) , see updated answer.